# Border and Flow Layouts

Tags: java, swing, border-layout, flowlayout

Okay, so I'm having some trouble with my Programming Exercise today.

The Exercise text goes like this:

(Use the **FlowLayout** manager) Write a program that meets the following requirements:

- Create a frame and set its layout to **FlowLayout**
- Create two panels and add them to the frame
- Each panel contains three buttons. The panel uses **FlowLayout**

The buttons should be named "Button 1", "Button 2" and so on. (i completed the original code)

Now i needed to change my code into **BorderLayout** while moving 1 panel to south, and the other to the center, i tried but it doesn't seem to come out correctly. The buttons are just on the top and bottom.

Original Code (**FlowLayout**):

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;

public class lab5_1 extends JFrame {

    public lab5_1() {
        setLayout(new FlowLayout());

        // Create two panels
        JPanel panel1 = new JPanel();
        JPanel panel2 = new JPanel();


        // Add three buttons to each panel
        panel1.add(new JButton(" Button 1 "));
        panel1.add(new JButton(" Button 2 "));
        panel1.add(new JButton(" Button 3 "));
        panel2.add(new JButton(" Button 4 "));
        panel2.add(new JButton(" Button 5 "));
        panel2.add(new JButton(" Button 6 "));


        // Add panels to frame
        add(panel1);
        add(panel2);

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        lab5_1 frame = new lab5_1();
        frame.setTitle(" Exercise 12_1 ");
        frame.setSize(600,75);
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null); // center frame
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

My attempt at the **BorderLayout**:

```
public class lab5_2 extends JFrame {

    public lab5_2() {
    setLayout(new BorderLayout());

     // Create two panels
        JPanel panel1 = new JPanel();
        JPanel panel2 = new JPanel();


        // Add three buttons to each panel
        panel1.add(new JButton(" Button 1 "));
        panel1.add(new JButton(" Button 2 "));
        panel1.add(new JButton(" Button 3 "));
        panel2.add(new JButton(" Button 4 "));
        panel2.add(new JButton(" Button 5 "));
        panel2.add(new JButton(" Button 6 "));

        //Add Panel to frame
        add(panel1, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        add(panel2, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
    }


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        lab5_2 frame = new lab5_2();
        frame.setTitle(" Exercise 12_2 ");
        frame.setSize(200, 200);
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null); // center frame
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Comment: IMO because you are not using (= filling) either the `NORTH` nor the `WEST`or `EAST` region, the `CENTER` region fills what space is left after `SOUTH` (at least i understand the [Oracle documentation - BorderLayout](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/BorderLayout.html) so). If it was not so, you would have seen *empty space* for the not used regions.

Comment: @pasty so my code is correct but the placement is off because the rest isn't filled in?

Comment: Agreed with pasty. The center portion will expand to fill all available space. Maybe show a picture of what you were expecting vs. what you got.

Comment: Yes - you need to add more elements (or move your existing elements) to another region or present your solution like this and explain the output. ;-)

Comment: @Takendarkk hmmm.. i wouldn't exactly know what it would look like it just didn't seem right, since it basically showed north and south but nothing in the center. I guess that's just what happens if you have nothing else filling the space.

Comment: @pasty Thanks for the quick answer, just wanted to make sure my code wasn't wrong(:

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The center area gets as much of the available space as possible. The other areas  expand only as much as necessary to fill all available space.